# How to convert or read CSS rem value to px?

Tags: jquery, css, height

I want to find the px value of height of html h1 element.

```js
var height = $("h1").height();
console.log(height);

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= height) {
    // ...
  } else {
    // ...
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Foo</h1>
```

`3.5rem` is `56px`

When I wrote `56px` at `h1` tag on CSS, then I can find the height `56px`. However If i wrote `3.5rem`, it doesn't calculate as `56px`.

I did test it with `.scrollTop` function.

Why do I not get the `3.5rem` to `56px` value, when I used `height()`?
How can I convert the `rem` value to `px`?

Comment: `font-szie` needs to be `font-size`, but I assume that's just a typo in the question.

Comment: function convertRemToPixels(rem) {    
    return rem * parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);
}

Comment: Also note that jQuery read the value from the DOM, and hence it will always return `px`, despite the unit used in the CSS value. You can see this from the snippet I edited in to your question. Given the snippet editor's default styles, `3.5rem` is around `65` pixels and returns as such in Chrome, Firefox and IE11 (and probably all other browsers, but I didn't test those). So in other words, I don't see any issues with your code and it should work as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `h1` as a container element like `div`, **Note:** these two elements has there own default styles, these default styles may sometimes differ in different browsers. What matters in this case is what is inside the `h1` html Element and the styles specified.. After understanding your question. You can achieve what you want by doing the following. If you want something different, let me know.

```js
var h1 = $('h1').css('font-size');
console.log(h1);

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= height) {
    // ...
  } else {
    // ...
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Foo</h1>
```